# how can i upload a single file to specified branch of specified project by java code , as there is no suitable api interface

Tags: java, file-upload, gitlab, gitlab-api

Anybody knows the implementation of function of uploading a entire file to a specific branch of a specific project on gitlab UI portal ?

I want to upload a single file to specified branch of specified project , but there is no suitable api interface. I have checked the gitlab api document, and there is `"POST /projects/:id/uploads"` which help upload a file to a project but not under the branch of the project ,  and `"/projects/:id/repository/files/:filePath"` which creates a new file under the 
specified branch of project but it only support content of file ,not a entire file. So, these two interfaces cannot solve my problem.

Does anyone face the issue ? any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have the commit API: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#create-a-commit-with-multiple-files-and-actions

This seems to be what you need.